# Как следует перевести термин posts?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Сейчас "posts" переводится как «сообщения», что не точно. На Stack Overflow "posts" используется только для ответов/вопросов, например, комментарии, сообщения в чате не называются "posts" обычно. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Также возможна путаница во всех тех местах, где "messages" также переведены как «сообщения».

Предлагаю явно каждый раз писать «вопросы/ответы».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

"posts" = «сообщения»

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- "posts" = «вопросы/ответы»

Answer (score 0):

А может быть, «Публикации»?

- Явно отличается от сообщений–messages.
- Понятно, что это не сообщения между пользователями, а публикуемые тексты.
- И акцент на авторство. Сообщение может быть и от системы, от бота — а вот у публикации есть автор–человек.