# Как перевести сообщение о ежедневном лимите голосов «за» и «против»?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, голоса-против, голоса-за

В transifex есть ряд сообщений, касающихся дневного лимита голосов «за» и «против». Их характерная особенность - вложенные кавычки в переводе, из-за чего приходится использовать кавычки-лапки.

Еще такая формулировка не вполне объясняет, какое именно «за» и «против» здесь имеется в виду (а имеются в виду сообщения — вопросы и ответы).

Предлагаю обдумать варианты перевода, которые не имеют вложенных кавычек.

(Ссылки ведут на Transifex, они здесь для удобства переводчиков).

[О голосах «за»](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262957?q=%22vote%20Up%20votes%22):

> You've reached the maximum of $dailyAllowedVotes$ Vote Up votes per day; come back $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества голосов за «Проголосовать „за“» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; возвращайтесь $todayEnd$

[О голосах «против»](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262957?q=%22vote%20Down%20votes%22):

> You've reached the maximum of $dailyAllowedVotes$ Vote Down votes per day; come back $todayEnd$
>
> → Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов за «Голосование „против“» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

Кроме них есть [аналогичные вопросы без вложенности](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262929?q=reached%20the%20maximum):

> You've reached the maximum of $dailyAllowedVotes$ Closure votes per day; come back $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов за «Закрытие» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

Comment: А как тогда будет переводиться, например, _You've reached the maximum of $dailyAllowedVotes$ Spam votes per day; come back $todayEnd$_?

Comment: @VladD:  Например, так:  «Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов за пометку (против пометки) сообщения как рекламного.»

Comment: @VladD: Мы же не за сам спам голосуем (хороший спам – плохой спам), а за то, считать сообщение таковым или не считать.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это не голоса, а сами пометки. То есть смысл должен быть «Вы достигли максимального суточного количества отметок сообщений как рекламных.» (Кажется.)

Comment: @VladD: да, в случае спама это именно пометки.

Comment: кстати, насколько я понимаю, вроде бы учитываются и голоса за комментарии, а не только за вопросы и ответы?

Comment: и, кстати, а почему разделены голоса «за» и «против»? разве они не в одну «копилку» идут?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: там на самом деле есть отдельные лимиты. То есть из общих 40 все не могут быть только за вопросы или только за ответы. Точных чисел не знаю. Голоса за комментарии не учитываются (в том числе для получения знаков).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin только сейчас понял вопрос. За и против действительно должны быть в одной куче.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: По результатам обсуждения внёс лидирующую версию ответа в transifex.

Comment: Для тех, у кого есть доступ: [ссылка](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english?q=You%27ve%20reached%20the%20maximum).

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте выбранный вариант ответа правильным. Что-то мне подсказывает, что @VladD уже обновил  строки в соответствии с голосованием.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Обновление**:

В комментариях @jfs предложил ещё более хороший вариант, привожу его здесь. (Если вы считаете, что старый вариант лучше, я их разделю для голосования.)

> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит голосов за сообщения — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит голосов против сообщений — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит принятых автором вопросов  — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит на закрытие вопросов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит на новые избранные вопросы — $dailyAllowedVotes$; возвращайтесь $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит пометок сообщений как спама — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит открытия конкурсов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

---

Ещё одно предложение — теперь банановый^W с дневным^W суточным лимитом. И традиционно без кавычек.

> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит голосов за сообщения — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит голосов против сообщений — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит принятых автором вопросов  — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит голосов за закрытие вопросов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит добавления вопросов в «Избранное» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; возвращайтесь $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит отметок сообщений как рекламных — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы исчерпали суточный лимит открытия конкурсов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

И т. д.

Comment: Вот я сам в заголовке вопроса использовал «лимит», а в ответе не догадался. )

Comment: "суточный лимит голосов **на** закрытие вопросов"

Comment: "суточный лимит на новые избранные вопросы"

Comment: "суточный лимит пометок сообщений как спам"

Comment: @jfs: я колебался между «спамом» и «рекламными сообщениями», это, наверное, стоит обсудить отдельно.

Comment: @jfs: А вот «лимит голосов на закрытие вопросов», по-моему, не очень хорошо звучит. Потому что кажется, что «на» относится не к лимиту, а к голосам, а «голоса на закрытие» — не сочетается.

Comment: @jfs: Возможно, лучше было бы «лимит на голосование/я за закрытие вопросов», но так слишком официально.

Comment: @VladD: да, слово "голосов" можно убрать: "суточный лимит на закрытие вопросов"

Comment: @jfs: О, а хороший вариант. Сделаете отдельным ответом?

Comment: [SO допускает рекламу](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/137096), но запрещает спам.

Comment: Думаю, достаточно текущий ответ поправить.

Comment: @jfs: Насчёт спама согласен, да.

Comment: @jfs: Внёс новые варианты.

Comment: Были какие-то предпосылки к переводу `come back` как `заходите ещё` вместо более очевидного `возвращайтесь`?

Comment: @alexolut: Исключительно личный стиль, возможно, слишком неофициально?

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант перевода:

> Вы сегодня использовали все $dailyAllowedVotes$ голоса "за" сообщения. Вы сможете продолжить голосовать голосовать "за" сообщения $todayEnd$.
>
> Вы сегодня использовали все $dailyAllowedVotes$ голоса "против" сообщений. Вы сможете продолжить голосовать "против" сообщений $todayEnd$.
>
> Вы сегодня использовали все $dailyAllowedVotes$ голоса о закрытии вопросов. Вы сможете продолжить голосовать о закрытии вопросов $todayEnd$.

И так далее, сколько их там есть.

Comment: «Сегодня» — не совсем точно, т. к. лимит даётся ЕМНИП на 24 часа (которые начинаются в полночь по UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки вообще не нужны при такой формулировке.

> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов за вопросы и ответы — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов против вопросов и ответов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

Answer (score 1):

Для вопросов и ответов есть [принятый термин «сообщения»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/483/181472). Это более лаконично, но неочевидно, что сюда не включаются, например, комментарии.

> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов за сообщения — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов против сообщений — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

Answer (score 1):

Ещё одно предложение — не использовать слово «голос» там, где это не обязательно. И избавиться от кавычек где только можно.

> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества голосов за сообщения — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества голосов против сообщений — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества принятых автором вопросов  — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества голосов за закрытие вопросов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества добавления вопросов в «Избранное» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; возвращайтесь $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества отметок сообщений как рекламных — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного количества открытия конкурсов — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$

И т. д.

Comment: «количество» вместо «значения» — гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Упрощаем до одного уровня и объясняем, что это за голоса.

> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов «за вопросы и ответы» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$
>
> Вы достигли максимального суточного значения голосов «против вопросов и ответов» — $dailyAllowedVotes$; заходите еще $todayEnd$