# "Прямые" кавычки в заголовке вопроса преобразуются в английские двойные

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация

в продолжение обсуждения: [Как следует писать кавычки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/493/178576)

тема кавычек затрагивается также здесь: [Как перевести сообщение о ежедневном лимите голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/670/178576)

---

заметил, что в заголовке **вопроса** пара прямых кавычек (`"текст"`) преобразуется в «[английские двойные кавычки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8)» (`“текст”`).

в *html-коде* страницы это выглядит как: `&ldquo;текст&rdquo;`, хотя в заголовке **страницы** (внутри тега `<title>`) присутствует верная запись: `&quot;текст&quot;`

В блоке связанных вопросов — английские кавычки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на вопрос остается с прямыми кавычками: ["Прямые" кавычки в заголовке вопроса преобразуются в английские двойные](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/822/).

посмотреть можно в заголовке данного вопроса или, например, этого: [Не срабатывает проверка состояния is(":hidden") с условием if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436581/178576).

Comment: кстати, в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22863596#22863596), вроде бы, «нормальные» кавычки: `&quot;`

Comment: Связанный: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27877/296059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не баг, это фича. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Автозамена обычных кавычек на английские — часть функционала [Smartypants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/). Заменяются следующие символы:

- Прямые кавычки ( `"` и `'` ) и составные из знаков (``` ``пример'' ```) на `“английские”` в HTML-кодах.
- Повторяющиеся [дефисы-минусы](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=-) (`--` и `---`) на [среднее тире](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=%E2%80%93) ([en-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash), `–`, `&ndash;`) и [длинное тире](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=%E2%80%94) ([em-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash), `—`, `&mdash;`) в HTML-кодах.
- Три последовательные точки (`...`) на HTML-код для [многоточия](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=%E2%80%A6)(`…`)

Об этом на Мете.SE:

- [Are double quotes being replaced in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38098/296059)
- [Curly quotes in titles revert to straight quotes after canceling an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190053/296059)

Comment: *Сразу после нее я вижу* — в процессе правки и сразу после сохранения правки код страницы формируется *javascript-ом*. а после обновления — загружается с сервера.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: т.е. client-side? А в остальных случаях чем формируется?

Comment: *client-side* — как раз всё верно делает. это с сервера загружается уже изменённый код. посмотрите предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: *Сомневаюсь, что такой feature-request пройдёт* — придётся с этим как-то жить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вы уверены, что стоит заменять на ёлочки, если в пример брать [указанный вами вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436581/)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: в коде на елочки заменять нельзя, да и лапки не очень уместны. Может быть, вовсе отключить автозамену?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: в коде нельзя ни на ёлочки, ни на лапки. В принципе я бы предпочёл видеть в заголовках ёлочки, но если выбор стои́т между несуществующим в русской пунктуации символом **“** и отсутствием автозамен — лучше отсутствие.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: про дефисы исправил, а про автозамену не понимаю, о чем вы спорите.

Comment: Я не особо спорю. Лишь советую выпилить басурманские кавычки в любом виде (автозамены или не авто). При этом сам умудрился запутаться в этих самых символах, тоже мне знаток типографики. **“** в русском как раз бывает, только не как левая (английская) кавычка, а как правая в паре „ … “; чего у нас вообще не бывает, так это символа **”**.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: про автозамену: скорее всего, отключить можно только целиком Smartypants. Автозамена в коде, конечно недопустима. Про кавычки: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498/181472

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: Опа… всё-таки я поторопился плюсануть ответ. Именование символа «–» дефисом исправлено, а вот его *использование в качестве дефиса* — нет **☺**

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: По вашему мнению, какой символ нужно использовать в качестве дефиса? Минус?

Comment: По моему мнению: «-» (U+002D). Но я вкусовые предпочтения никому не навязываю; нравится Вам U+2010 или U+2011 — на здоровье. Лишь бы дефисом не объявлялось то (U+2013), что им не является.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Похоже, вы разбираетесь в знаках пунктуации лучше меня. Может быть, напишете руководство для переводчиков и техписателей на Мете? Перевод и формирование разделов Справки в самом разгаре. Ваши инструкции будут очень кстати.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: Вот, сделал: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150/189014