# «разнобой» в информации об исчерпании лимитов на странице проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

**связанная тема**: [Как перевести сообщение о ежедневном лимите голосов «за» и «против»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/670/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2/699#699)

вроде бы, решено использовать однообразную схему, а сейчас
на странице [проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) при исчерпании лимита в 20 проверок — текст идёт «вразнобой»:

[image: сообщения об исчерпании лимитов]

присутствуют такие варианты:

1. Общее количество голосований за закрытие, которое вы проверили сегодня, составило 20.
2. Общее количество первых сообщений, проверенных Вами сегодня, составило 20.
3. Сегодня Вы проверили сообщений низкого качества в количестве: 20.

**предложение**: унифицировать тексты.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. [Поправил](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/41447178?q=Thank%20you%20for%20reviewing) в соответствии с терминами, принятыми в указанном вами обсуждении. Строки будут доступны после ближайшего обновления движка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/838/#comment2462_838) от [NicolasChabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky):

Спасибо за замечание. Поправил в соответствии с терминами, принятыми в указанном вами обсуждении. Строки будут доступны после ближайшего обновления движка.