# Содержимое или контент?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, термины, справка

В различных текстах справки и вопросах меты периодически встречаются два варианта одного и того же термина: «содержимое» и «контент». Предлагаю выбрать один из них и удалить другой.

[Почему так важно принимать участие в оценке вопросов и ответов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

> - ...хорошее **содержимое** всегда будет в верхней части страницы;
> - ...неверное **содержимое** опустится в самый низ страницы;
> - ...пользователи, которые постоянно создают полезный **контент**, получают репутацию и больше привилегий на сайте.

[«Содержимое» на Мете.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC*)

[«Контент» на Мете.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82*)

Связанный вопрос: [Как следует перевести термин posts?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/483/181472)

Comment: На мой взгляд, вопрос немножко не корректен. Пожалуйста, поясните, вы предлагаете несколько вариантов перевода для конкретных строк или перевода вообще? Для конкретный строк мы можем подобрать более точные определения такие как "вопросы" и "ответы", но зачастую под термином "содержимое" понимают все тексты на сайте. Во втором случае, на мой взгляд, следует использовать общий термин.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: согласен, нужно уточнять. Эти строки — только пример. Но в общем случае есть два взаимозаменяемых термина и нужно один из них исключить. Вопрос об этом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следует руководствоваться следующими правилами.

1. Использовать термин «**содержимое**» в общем случае, когда речь идет о всей информации на сайте.
2. Использовать термин «**сообщения**», когда из контекста не ясно, о чем идет речь: о вопросах, ответах или комментариях, а также в случаях, когда речь идет о любом типе: вопросе, ответе или комментарии.
3. Во всех остальных случаях, для сообщений, следует использовать конкретные термины: «**вопрос**», «**ответ**», «**комментарий**».
4. Использовать конкретные термины, если из контекста понятно о чем идет речь. Например, «**метка**», «**описание метки**», «**учётная запись пользователя**» и т. д.

Comment: Описания меток относятся к сообщениям или только к содержимому?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Поправил ответ. Ответ общий, если вы видите какой-либо недостаток, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку!

Answer (score 7):

Мне кажется, оба слова — и «содержимое», и «контент» — имеют небольшой оттенок пренебрежительного отношения к вкладу участников. (Как и их синоним «наполнение».) Может быть, называть вещи более конкретно?

> - ... хорошие вопросы всегда будут в верхней части страницы;
> - ... некачественные вопросы опустятся в самый низ страницы;
> - ... пользователи, которые постоянно задают интересные вопросы или дают полезные ответы, получают репутацию и больше привилегий на сайте.

Comment: Согласен про пренебрежительное отношение. Для меня «контент» и «наполнение» — что–то, что «пипл хавает», товар, некая аморфная масса текста. А «содержимое» немного отдает канцелярщиной. Хотел было предложить «публикации» или «материалы» — то же ощущение.

Comment: А что делать, если под «содержимым» понимается более широкое понятие, например в «модерировании содержимого»?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Хороший вопрос. Можно попробовать уточнить, что именно является содержимым. «Модерирование вопросов и ответов»? «Модерирование общения»? «Модерирование чата»? «Модерирование комментариев»?

Comment: вот на этом месте у меня возник этот вопрос. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/77

Comment: @NickVolynkin: По-моему, «модерирование контента сайта» ничем не отличается от просто «модерирования». Тем более, не сразу понятно, считаются ли строки интерфейса сайта контентом. Я бы написал, например, «модерирование сообщений участников сайта и их поведения» (но часть про поведение меняет смысл правки).

Answer (score -1):

### Содержимое

Как и с остальными терминами: если есть незаимствованный вариант, используем его.

> - ...хорошее **содержимое** всегда будет в верхней части страницы;
> - ...неверное **содержимое** опустится в самый низ страницы;
> - ...пользователи, которые постоянно создают полезное **содержимое**, получают репутацию и больше привилегий на сайте.