# Новая страница справки о переводах вопросов и ответов со Stack Overflow на английском на русский язык

Tags: обсуждение, справка

Большое спасибо всем, кто высказался в вопросе «[Нужны ли переводы на Stack Overflow? Если да, какой вы видите систему?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8371/6)» Согласно отзывам в этом и [предыдущем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/6) вопросах, сообщество считает хорошие переводы на нашем сайте пользой, а не чем–то негативным. Участники воспринимают их аналогично вопросам со своим ответом.

На мой взгляд, лучший следующий шаг — описать полученный консенсус в справочном центре. Я подготовил и добавил новый раздел справки «[Следует ли переводить вопросы со Stack Overflow на английском на русский язык?](/help/translate-from-english)»

Пожалуйста, посмотрите на страницу справки и поделитесь вашими мыслями и замечаниями! Буду рад вместе с вами сделать эту страницу еще лучше!

Comment: Не хватает букв **ё**. А они [должны быть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/176217).

Comment: @älёxölüt Напишите, пожалуйста, где поправить, сделаю.

Comment: Вы серьёзно? Не знаете в каких словах из текста буква **ё** должна быть вместо **е**?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky слова "определённо", "ещё", "чём", "всё". Вроде бы всё (поиск по букве "е" в браузере)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky к тому же пунктуацию стоит поправить: "к поисковику, "(убрать запятую), "помнить_делая перевод"(добавить запятую), "делая перевод_вы"(добавить запятую)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и буква "ю" пропущена в "возможность_"

Comment: @cppquestions большое спасибо! Поправил.

Answer (score 3):

1. > Не забывайте отблагодарить авторов вопроса и ответов обратной ссылкой на сообщение на английском языке.

   Я бы заменил "обратной ссылкой на сообщение" на "ссылкой на сообщение-источник".

   И правильно ли я понимаю, что этот момент правил официально закрепляет то, что при переводе достаточно ссылки на оригинальное сообщение без ссылки на профиль его автора?
2. Никак не оговаривается оформление и получение репутации (хотя на мете раньше обсуждалось). Полагаю, что стоит как-то в явном виде прописать что

   - Не надо помещать весь текст сообщения в цитату
   - Не надо делать сообщение общим, репутация, полученная за перевод является заслуженной
3. Возможно, стоит дополнительно акцентировать внимание на том, что перевод должен быть качественным, а не автоматическим. В принципе этот момент затрагивается фразами о понимании переводимой темы, но, возможно, стоит это отметить прямо?

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Отвечая на ваши вопросы. (1) Лицензию следует соблюдать полностью, в том числе ссылаться на профиль участника. (2) Внизу есть пояснение, что переводы аналогичны вопросам с ответом от автора (вопрос про необходимость объявлять общим). (3) Пункт про машинный перевод был, но я его удалил, так как без контекста он смотрится неуместным (кому в голову придет писать бота, который будет автоматически робопереводы добавлять?) В остальном согласен, поправлю.

Comment: Если у вас есть конкретные предложения по высказанным замечания, буду благодарен, если поделитесь!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 1. Тогда это стоит указать. 2. Да, но всё же тут надо додумывать. Чем чётче сформулировано, тем лучше. 3. Ну бота-то нет, но можно и просто "о, хороший вопрос, переведу-ка", а дальше в гуглопереводчик. 4. По формулировкам идей нет, а то бы сразу предложил.

Comment: Спасибо. Поправил!

Answer (score 2):

Дополнения и замечания:

*"Если вы нашли полезный вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском"* или на Испанском или другом языке, или на другом подсайте сети. У нас же много подсайтов для программистов, подходящих под тематику ruSO (которая шире enSO). Стоит это обозначить.

*"Создать мир, в котором на каждый запрос к поисковику, в выдаче есть ссылка на развёрнутый ответ на русском языке."* - а вот это наоборот слишком инклюзивно. Стоит все же ограничиться словами про Базу Знаний для программистов.

*"обратной ссылкой на сообщение на английском языке."* ссылкой на вопрос и ответ, а не на "сообщение".

*"пользуйтесь этой возможность движка"* слишком фамильярно. Наверно всё же не движка, а платформы.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Поменял «движок» на «платформу», хотя про фамильярность не понял. [Когда–то давно мы приняли решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/483/) о том, что будем адресовать «вопрос или ответ» «сообщением». Про SO/SE согласен, поправил. Формулировка цели взята из [манифеста](/help/manifesto).  Если менять, то необходимо сразу и там, а это отдельная тема.

Comment: Про фамильярность имел ввиду в отношении "движка". Это мы его тут по-свойски так называем, а для более широкой аудитории это "платформа". Ну или типа того.

Answer (score 2):

Хорошо бы привлечь участников из сообщества "Русский Язык", но пока мне кажется, что:

- не хватает запятой:

  > нет на Stack Overflow на русском (,) и этот вопрос
- Предложение из предыдущего пункта довольно длинное, его хорошо бы разбить, но я пока не очень представляю как это сделать хорошо. Для начала можно "например, на Stack Overflow на английском" взять в скобки вместо запятых.
- Следовало бы окавычить (ёлочками) названия типа "Stack Overflow на английском", "Stack Overflow на русском".
- "английский" стоит привести как пример, во всех других случаях стоит использовать более широкий термин "иностранный". Иначе можно подумать, что переводы, скажем, с испанского SO не приветствуются вдруг.
- Опечатка. Вместо "Чем" должно быть "Чей":

  > Чем перевод, того и репутация
- Убрать бы точки в конце предложений из секции "Дополнительно".
- Заменить в заголовке "вопросы" на "сообщения". Вполне может быть ситуация, когда очень похожий вопрос уже имеется на русском языке, а вот ответ ещё не успели <s>cворовать</s> перевести просто потому, что не знали о наличии вопроса-ответов на сайте с иным языком общения.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания. Большинство поправил. Не до конца понимаю, почему должна быть запятая. Также я бы ограничился «английским» и «Stack Overflow» (хотя уже перешли к Stack Exchange). С большой уверенностью можно говорить, что основным источником переводов выступает Stack Overflow на английском. Хотелось бы в явном виде описать именно этот сценарий, чтобы было предельно понятно и не перегружено.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky запятая, потому что сложное предложение (вы нашли) и (вопрос соответствует). А насчёт кавычек вокруг "Stack Overflow на русском", это, имхо, стоит глобально по всем статьям из справки пройти. И, кстати, пора бы базу обновить. А ещё стоит уточнить у РуЯз на тему запятой или дефиса в "Чей перевод, того и репутация".

Comment: Про дефис тоже думал :) Зададите вопрос?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky некогда работать надо :) казнить нельзя помиловать

Answer (score 0):

> Следует ли переводить сообщения с английского языка на русский?

Я бы **английский** поменял бы на **иностранный**, так как помимо английского SO есть и другие SO по конкретным языкам. Может быть кто-то на индийском полезный ответ найдет...

Comment: Спасибо! Полностью согласен, но все–таки хочу настоять на текущей формулировке. Мысль в том, что есть основной тренд «английский + Stack Overflow», который бы хотелось выделить, и при этом не перегружать справку. Если в будущем возникнут разногласия о том, стоит ли переводить с Мандарина, будем уточнять!

Comment: Такая мысль уже высказана в другом (неожиданно, моём) ответе :)